# Multiple jquery events in Marionette ItemView (hover not working)

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, marionette

How can I fire mutiple jquery events in the same line in Marionette ItemView? 
Eg. If I want to have the same code for `click` and `hover` events. I want to do something like -
`events: { 
"click, hover .class1": "doSomething"
// Other events 
}`

 
1. Code above is obviously wrong, how can I make it right? 
2. Also, `hover` doesn't work at all in Marionette ItemView events, on the other hand, `click` works fine when used individually. Is that a marionette issue?

Comment: You should only ask one question per post. Your first question is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/10811067/2333214. Your second question might  actually help someone in future, but its answer is buried in comments since you asked like this and accepted an answer which only answers the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just split them up:

```
events: { 
  "click .class1": "doSomething",
  "hover .class1": "doSomething"
}
```

`hover` will not work however, since jquery dropped the support for that in version 1.9.

Comment: Ok, also, for the second part - hover, I found - http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event (it says `hover` is no longer supported after jquery 1.9!

Comment: @Tholle did you get a notification about my comment on question..? Just wondering how you updated the 3 hour old answer within 3 minutes after  my comment on question

Comment: @TJ Yes I did, strangely enough. Thanks for correcting me.